# How to display products in Flatlist properly?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to display some fetched products in a `FlatList`, also to display more products when I reach the end of this `FlatList`, but I am getting this error: `Invariant Violation: ScrollView child layout (["alignItems"]) must be applied through the contentContainerStyle prop`.

When I change `alignItems` from `style` to `contentContainerStyle` the app closes without showing an error or alert.

If I remove the `alignItems` from `container` the app closes too

```
export default function NewProducts() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false);
  const [startLimit, setStartLimit] = useState({ start: 0, limit: 10 });
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setisLoading(true);
    getProducts();
  }, [startLimit]);

  const gotoProduct = (id) => {
    navigation.push("product", { idProduct: id });
  };

  const getProducts = async () => {
    const response = await getLastProductsApi(
      startLimit.start,
      startLimit.limit
    );
    console.log(response);
    setProducts(response);
  };

  const renderItem = ({product}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={product.id}
        onPress={() => gotoProduct(product.id)}
      >
        <View style={styles.containerProduct}>
          <View style={styles.product}>
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={{
                uri: `${product.attributes.images.data[0].attributes.formats.small.url}`,
              }}
            />
            <Text style={styles.name} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">
              {product.attributes.title}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  };

  const renderFooter = () => {
    return isLoading && <Loading text="Loading more products" size="medium" />;
  };

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setStartLimit({
      start: startLimit.start + 10,
      limit: startLimit.limit + 10,
    });
    setisLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.container}
      numColumns={2}
      data={products}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    marginTop: 1,
  },
  containerProduct: {
    padding: 3,
  },
  product: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  image: {
    height: 150,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  name: {
    marginTop: 15,
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});
```

Here is where I call this component

```
export default function Home() {

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBarCustom
        backgroundColor={colors.primary}
        barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <Search />
      <View>
        <Banner />
        <NewProducts />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but to my knowledge, and testing it on the documentation's playground.... `renderItem` will just give you `item`. You are pulling "product" which is in line with the data and makes sense theoretically. But I'm pretty sure you have to change:

`const renderItem = ({product}) =>`
to
`const renderItem = ({item}) =>`

Answer (score 3):

When you use `renderItem` from FlatList you have to use `item` and not `product`: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem

You can replace

```
const renderItem = ({product}) => {
```

By

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
```